# Dictionary Failure binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, binding

I have most of the textblock and radio button objects in my app bound to my dictionnary

I store the new value in a Dictionary.

The problem is that the binding failure is throwing an exception that is very slow.

Here is an example: (this code runs correctly, it is just slow if it can't find a match in the start app.)

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Dictio[0], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Dictio[1], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="select" IsChecked="{Binding Dictio[2], Mode=TwoWay}" Content="true"/>
</stackPanel>
```

And in my class

```
    private Dictionary<int, object> _Dictio;

 public MainWindow()
        {
            Dictio = new Dictionary<int, object>();
            this.DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

public Dictionary<int, object> Dictio
        {
            get { return _Dictio; }
            set { _Dictio = value; }
        }

private void test(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, object> kvp in Dictio)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
}
```

When I try to start app and the binding tries to lookup Dictio[key], I get this in my output window for all the key of my dictionnary Dictio:

```
 System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'Item[]' value (type 'Object') from 'Dictio' (type 'Dictionary`2'). BindingExpression:Path=Dictio[4]; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name=''); target element is 'RadioButton' (Name='mm'); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1') TargetInvocationException:'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Une exception a été levée par la cible d'un appel. ---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: La clé donnée était absente du dictionnaire.
   à System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---
   à System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   à System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   à System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   à System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
   à MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.GetValue(Object item, Int32 level)
   à MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.RawValue(Int32 k)'
```

Is there a way to make the connection not throw an exception if the dictionary is empty

Comment: You could bind using a converter which would check the size of the dictionary before returning a value

Comment: can you explain more please about the converter how can i develop, if you have an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also initialize the dictionary with empty values and then set binding mode to OneWayToSource like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    Dictio = new Dictionary<int, object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        Dictio.Add(i, new object());
    }
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}

<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Dictio[0], Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Dictio[1], Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Yes, finally i success my binding without error thanks @Miro Bucko

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to override the `Dictionary<int, object>`.

```
public class CustomDictionary : IEnumerable
{
    private Dictionary<int, Tuple<DependencyObject, DependencyProperty>> properties = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<DependencyObject, DependencyProperty>>();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var item in properties)
        {
            yield return  new KeyValuePair<int, object>(item.Key, item.Value.Item1.GetValue(item.Value.Item2));
        }
    }

    public void Add(int index, DependencyObject obj, DependencyProperty property)
    {
        properties.Add(index, new Tuple<DependencyObject, DependencyProperty>(obj, property));
    }

    public object this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return properties[index].Item1.GetValue(properties[index].Item2);
        }
        set
        {
            properties[index].Item1.SetCurrentValue(properties[index].Item2, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then instead of using Dictionary everywhere you would use CustomDictionary like so:

```
private CustomDictionary _Dictio;

public CustomDictionary Dictio
{
    get { return _Dictio; }
    set { _Dictio = value; }
}
```

Also in your MainWindow you have to initialize the Dictio AFTER you call InitializeComponent() like so:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Dictio = new CustomDictionary();
    Dictio.Add(0, textBox1, TextBox.TextProperty);
    Dictio.Add(1, textBox2, TextBox.TextProperty);
    Dictio.Add(2, radioButton, RadioButton.IsCheckedProperty );

    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

This will add the instance of the DependencyObjects and the corresponding DependencyProperty, that you want to bind to, to the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for response but when i'd like to display the content of Dictio i have the error example of my function                    private void test(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(Dictio[1]);}                           and i have the error  "l'exception NullReferenceException n'a pas été gérée"

Comment: Have you initialized the Dictio before you tried displaying its elements?

Comment: how can I initialized the Dictio, I want to fill the dictio through the xaml file as shown above

Comment: I see. Then you can either create the converter OR bind them in code behind.

Comment: I have changed the answer, try it and let me know

Comment: No, I was not able to retrieve the value from the dictionary                    my problem is that i have a quizz with 150 question, i want bind the response in the dictionnary for save them in the data base after. that's why i use the binding in my textbox and radio button in xaml file just i have the error that explain first time

Comment: I have tried running your test() function on the code with CustomDictionary and it printed out all the correct values. Can you tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I use your class CustomDictionary

this's my xaml file

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="textBox1" Text="{Binding Dictio[0], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBox Name="textBox2" Text="{Binding Dictio[1], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <RadioButton Name="radioButton" GroupName="select" IsChecked="{Binding Dictio[2], Mode=TwoWay}" Content="true"/>
<Button Content="test" Click="test"/>
</StackPanel>
```

in my class

```
    private CustomDictionary _Dictio;

 public MainWindow()
        {
            Dictio = new CustomDictionary();
            this.DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    public CustomDictionary Dictio
            {
                get { return _Dictio; }
                set { _Dictio = value; }
            }

    private void test(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, object> kvp in Dictio)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            }
    }
```

when i execute i have this error

```
Une exception de première chance de type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' s'est produite dans mscorlib.dll
```

in your class CustomDictionnary in

```
 return properties[index].Item1.GetValue(properties[index].Item2);
```

Comment: You forgot to add the elements into the Dictio like I did in the answer. Also you should not bind in the xaml.

Comment: i want bind in the xaml because i have more to 150 control, so i can't add all the control in the behind code i want bind them in the xaml that's why

Comment: Can you give example of how the control looks? (xaml)

Comment: Same as in the example xaml file I put up that contains textbox and radio buttons. But I can not initialize the controls from the constructor. this is a quiz so I have to store the responses in the "Dictio" dictionary to save later in the databases

Comment: I dont see why you cannot initialize the dictionary from the constructor. What does your MainWindow.xaml look like?

Comment: i want binding the control in xaml, i dont want initialize the dictionary from the constructor like Dictio.Add(0, textBox1, TextBox.TextProperty);........Dictio.Add(150, textBox1, TextBox.TextProperty); the solution that i have run correctly just it display the error and the execution is slow so just i'd like that i eliminate this error